# How to use IsDirty() property of android view

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I am developing application using android3.0. I need to update the previously drawn canvas. While searching for this I have seen "isDirty()" of View class in Android API documentation.

But I did not get much cleared information about this. Could please suggest me "how to set the part of canvas is to dirty and update just that part ?".

Answer (score 0):

The View method `invalidate(…)` will do this. You can invalidate the whole view by passing no parameters, or pass it a `Rect` to invalidate a region of it.